# Notice: Undefined offset по непонятным мне причинам

Tags: php, массивы

Есть массив:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [order_id] => 4
                    [entry_id] => 5
                    [count] => 1
                    [price] => 1
                    [weight] => 0
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [order_id] => 4
                    [entry_id] => 2
                    [count] => 1
                    [price] => 94.4
                    [weight] => 0.5
                )

            [2] => Array
                (
                    [order_id] => 4
                    [entry_id] => 1
                    [count] => 1
                    [price] => 38
                    [weight] => 2
                )

        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [order_id] => 3
                    [entry_id] => 4
                    [count] => 1
                    [price] => 0
                    [weight] => 0
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [order_id] => 3
                    [entry_id] => 5
                    [count] => 1
                    [price] => 1
                    [weight] => 0
                )

            [2] => Array
                (
                    [order_id] => 3
                    [entry_id] => 2
                    [count] => 1
                    [price] => 94.4
                    [weight] => 0.5
                )

            [3] => Array
                (
                    [order_id] => 3
                    [entry_id] => 1
                    [count] => 1
                    [price] => 38
                    [weight] => 2
                )

        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [order_id] => 2
                    [entry_id] => 2
                    [count] => 1
                    [price] => 94.4
                    [weight] => 0.5
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [order_id] => 2
                    [entry_id] => 1
                    [count] => 1
                    [price] => 38
                    [weight] => 2
                )

        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [order_id] => 1
                    [entry_id] => 2
                    [count] => 1
                    [price] => 94.4
                    [weight] => 0.5
                )

        )

)
```

И скрипт:

```
$template_orders_prepare = array();

for($j = 0; $j < count($orders_prepare_list); $j++) {
 for($h = 0; $h < count($orders_prepare_list[$j]); $h++) {
  $order_id = $orders_prepare_list[$j][$h]['order_id'];
  $entry_id = $orders_prepare_list[$j][$h]['entry_id'];

  $template_orders_prepare[$order_id] = $entry_id;
 }
}

print_r($template_orders_prepare);
```

Проблема конкретно в этой строке, т.к. `entry_id` отдаётся самый последний, хотя их несколько:

```
$template_orders_prepare[$order_id] = $entry_id;
```

И чтобы отдавать их несколько, я сделал так:

```
$template_orders_prepare[$order_id] .= $entry_id;
```

И заработало как нужно (`print_r($template_orders_prepare);`).

Было:

```
Array
(
    [4] => 1
    [3] => 1
    [2] => 1
    [1] => 2
)
```

Стало:

```
(
    [4] => 521
    [3] => 4521
    [2] => 21
    [1] => 2
)
```

Но не всё так просто. Казалось бы, выводит всё как нужно, но непонятно откуда, вылезают следующие ошибки:

```
Notice: Undefined offset: 4 in ...

Notice: Undefined offset: 3 in ...

Notice: Undefined offset: 2 in ...

Notice: Undefined offset: 1 in ...
```

Которые указывают на эту несчастную строку:

```
$template_orders_prepare[$order_id] .= $entry_id;
```

Что только я не делал, раз 5 наверное всё переписывал и безрезультатно. Промучавшись 2 часа, я так и не понял, почему такое происходит, но при этом и массив содержит то, что нужно..

Comment: потому что конструкция `$template_orders_prepare[$order_id] .= $entry_id;` говорит сконкатенировать с содержимым элемента массива, которого нет.

Comment: @Etki, вот оно что.. Как-нибудь можно переписать эту конструкцию?

Comment: `$template_orders_prepare[$order_id] = $entry_id;`

Comment: @Etki, в таком случае выводится только последний $entry_id, а их несколько. В посте написал об этом.

Comment: Извините, но я не могу подробно читать два-три монитора. Проверяйте наличие элемента, если нет, то создавайте, если есть, то дополняйте. Зачем вам все это в строку сбивать - ума не приложу.

Comment: @Etki, пока не совсем понятно наличие какого элемента проверять. Парился с этим 2 часа и ничего не вышло. Так что надеюсь, что кто-то поможет.

Comment: того, в который конкатенируете

Comment: @Etki, можете написать код? Я не догоняю :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

делайте вот так:

```
$template_orders_prepare[$order_id][] = $entry_id;
```

а после вложенного цикла можно объединить через implode:

`$template_orders_prepare[$order_id] = implode('', $template_orders_prepare[$order_id])`;

Comment: Это прекрасно! Огромное спасибо Вам, выручили как никогда!

Comment: чей-то как никогда? :)) удачи!

Answer (score 1):

```
$template_orders_prepare = array();

for($j = 0; $j < count($orders_prepare_list); $j++) {
 for($h = 0; $h < count($orders_prepare_list[$j]); $h++) {
  $order_id = $orders_prepare_list[$j][$h]['order_id'];
  $entry_id = $orders_prepare_list[$j][$h]['entry_id'];

  // если элемент не существует, то надо его подготовить для использования, чтобы PHP не исправлял эту ситуацию сам - для него это выглядит, как ошибка
  if (!isset($template_orders_prepare[$order_id])) {
    $template_orders_prepare[$order_id] = array();
  }
  $template_orders_prepare[$order_id][] = $entry_id;
 }
}

print_r($template_orders_prepare);
```